# i want the page to be loaded fully with all the elements on it and then perform the click action on one of the specified button in selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium

Im new to selenium webdriver java. I,m unable to click on a button on a page. This page will be displayed following a click action on a link.Its showing error message in console " Element is not clickable " with some coordinates.Tried implicit wait, thread sleep, find element and click etc. but still same problem. the issue is in firefox and chrome but ok in IE.
Can someone help me pls.
regards
sri

Comment: Make sure element is visible on page when you trying to click it. Maybe you should scroll down the page

Comment: Thanks. the element is located on top right corner . and its enabled. still not working.

Comment: Please add some relevant HTML

Comment: Even after thread sleep if you are not able to click the element then it has nothing to do with loading of the page. You need to double check the CSS selector you are using. Check if the element is displayed, is clickable and then try clicking.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.refreshed(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element)));
```

Comment: thanks , it didnt worked this way either , but as i said in above comments, thread.sleep(10000)  holding page for a long time before click action on the desired button worked.

Comment: then change the sleep time to the in the webdriverwait. Have you tried that?

Comment: Then retry if it fails. Catch the exception and try again.

Answer (score -1):

Only a guess (so please don't be hasty in marking down) but it sounds to me like you have some JavaScript that is not fully loaded that performs the click functionality.  Consider not using CDN and bring your libraries in locally, disabling the button by default and enabling it when javascript fully loaded.